# Python multiprocessing lock strange behavior

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I notice a behaviour in my code that I cannot explain. This is the code:

```
import multiprocessing
from collections import deque

LOCK = multiprocessing.Lock()

data = deque(['apple', 'orange', 'melon'])

def f(*args):
    with LOCK:
        data.rotate()
        print data[0]

pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
pool.map(f, range(4))
```

I expect that the output would be

```
melon
orange
apple
melon
```

but instead I get

```
melon
melon
melon
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's got nothing to do with the `Lock`.  Each worker process, on Linux-y systems, inherits its own _copy_ of the main process's address space (read up on `fork()`) at the time the `Pool` is created.  So they each get their own copy of `data`, and nothing any process does to its copy can have any effect on the copy in any other process.

Answer (score 1):

As Tim Peters commented, the problem is not the `Lock` but that the `deque` is not shared across the processes but every process will have their own copy.

There are some data structures provided by the `multiprocessing` module which will be shared across processes, e.g. [`multiprocessing.Queue`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue). Use that instead.

Comment: I believe the multiprocessing.Queue is better suited for interprocess communication. What I wanted to achieve is to have a shared in-memory list, to act as an in-memory database. The better solutions are in the [Sharing state between processes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes) doc.